# Cannot set innodb_buffer_pool_size above 1023M in my.ini

Tags: mysql, buffer-pool, mysql-8.0

Windows server 2012 R2 with 64GB RAM, MySQL 8. The Database is about 5GB.

I am using a buffer pool of 1023M, as shown below:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1023M
```

If I enter anything above 1023M e.g. 1024M or 2G then MySQL will not start and the following appears in the errorlog:

> "Configuring persisted options failed: "Variable
>   'innodb_buffer_pool_size' can't be set to the value of '8388608'".

If I use the value 8388608, then it starts (which is ironic) but that's not enough.

When running using:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=10737418240;
```

It starts fine and sets the pool to 10GB - but that reverts back when rebooted.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Please show us the config file.  There is nothing obviously wrong; perhaps something nearby is confusing the parser.  What is the name of the file you changed?

Answer (score 2):

"Persisted options" is new in 8.0.  See if this works:

```
SET PERSIST innodb_buffer_pool_size=10737418240;
```

For more info:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html

Comment: Yay for PERSIST (for those pesky variables you test and forgot about until you reboot and realize it a week later) !!!

Comment: Many thanks for that - that is exactly the answer I was looking for. I have tried it tested it and it works. No idea how I was supposed to know that. In fact (coming from sql server) seeing as innodb_buffer_pool_size seems to be the most important setting to set - using  lot of data is useless without it - I would have thought that it would have been in a really obvious place in sql workbench whereas it doesn't appear there at all. Thanks again - really appreciated.

Comment: That is virtually the only tunable that needs changing for a new installation.